# Parallelize the processing of a list of 25 objects in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a function which takes in one input. I want to run the same function on 25 different inputs and finally combine the results of the 25 function calls. How do I do this in python? Will multithreading or multiprocessing be the better approach? I'm doing it on my work laptop and using the following approach:

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
output = pool.map(get_results, response_obj)
```

It's taking longer than even serially processing the objects. The functions is performing GET requests to an API.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Search SO there are probably many Q&A's relavent to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have asked questions before. I did not find anything which was directly relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally said that using an **asynchronous approach** is best practice for **get-requests**. There's plenty of libraries & other resources on asynchronous programming in **Python**.

To get your feet wet you should take a look at `asyncio`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html